# using boost file system in boost unit test global fixture error

Tags: c++, boost, ifstream

i try to do the following line inside global fixture but it give me error.
file is path with following :

```
 D:\\back_up_starting_1_18_2020\\visual_studio_programs_all_last_2020\\visual_studio\\Projects\\c++\\c++_2020_3_17_ninety47\\dukascopy-master\\dukascopy-master\\..\\test\\data\\raw\\GBPJPY\\2012\\11\\03\\01h_ticks.bin

file = fs::canonical(file);
```

i removed code to set up path and when i remove ".." my code works fine
is line  file = fs::canonical(file); wrong????

update:
i found that the problem is not related to boost unit test but it is related to ifstream.
so i made this concise code to reproduce the problem.

```
// ifstream_arg.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
// ifstream constructor.
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main() {

    std::string filename = "./test.txt";
    //const char * filename = "./test.txt";

    fs::path file(filename);

    file = fs::canonical(file);
    std::cout << filename << '\n';
    std::cout << file.generic_string() << '\n';
    std::cout << file.string() << '\n';
    std::cout << file.string().c_str() << '\n';
    std::cout << file.c_str() << '\n';
    ////filename = ("\\\\?\\" + file.generic_string()).c_str();
    filename = file.generic_string().c_str();
    std::cout << filename << '\n';

    //std::ifstream ifs("test.txt", std::ifstream::in);
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ifstream::binary);

    char c = ifs.get();

    while (ifs.good()) {
        std::cout << c;
        c = ifs.get();
    }

    ifs.close();

    return 0;
}
```

when i use file name as  string the ifstream works fine.
But when i use it as pointer to const char it gives error.
i read std::ifstream usage and it says that ifstream can work with both string and pointer to const char????
what is my error??

Answer (score 0):

i found the error.
it is in line:

```
filename = file.generic_string().c_str();
```

here the pointer returned from rhs points to result of generic_string() which is rvalue destroyed at end of expression so filename become dangling pointer and error happens.
So i either pass the whole rhs expression to ifstream Or set variable with it

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you use a prebuilt library for this engine and want to pass objects like string from/to the lib, you need to have the exactly correct build settings.